# Negative determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
-a_{12}-a_{13}-a_{14} & a_{12} & a_{13} & 1\\
a_{21} & -a_{21}-a_{23}-a_{24} & a_{23} & 1\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & -a_{31} - a_{32} - a_{34} & 1\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where all $a_{ij}$'s are positive reals. If we [explicitly calculate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20%5B%20%5B-a_%7B12%7D-a_%7B13%7D-a_%7B14%7D%20%2C%20a_%7B12%7D%20%2C%20a_%7B13%7D%20%2C%201%5D%20%2C%20%5B%20a_%7B21%7D%20%2C%20-a_%7B21%7D-a_%7B23%7D-a_%7B24%7D%20%2C%20a_%7B23%7D%20%2C%201%20%5D%2C%20%5B%20a_%7B31%7D%20%2C%20a_%7B32%7D%20%2C%20-a_%7B31%7D%20-%20a_%7B32%7D%20-%20a_%7B34%7D%20%2C%201%20%5D%2C%20%5B%20a_%7B41%7D%20%2C%20a_%7B42%7D%20%2C%20a_%7B43%7D%20%2C%201%5D%5D) the determinant of $A$ and factor whole expression, then we can easily see that $\det(A) < 0$.

Is it possible to prove that $\det(A) < 0$ (or that $\det(A) \neq 0$ if it is easier) using some matrix manipulations without calculating it directly?

Comment: Let me replace the four $1$s in the last column by four new positive reals $a_{15}, a_{25}, a_{35}, a_{45}$. Let me call the new matrix $A'$. Also, we insert a new column $\left(a_{14}, a_{24}, a_{34}, -a_{41} -a_{42} -a_{43} -a_{45}\right)^T$ between the $3$-rd and $4$-th columns of this matrix, and we insert a new row $\left(a_{51}, a_{52}, a_{53}, a_{54}, -a_{51} -a_{52} -a_{53} -a_{54}\right)$ at the very bottom of the matrix, where $a_{51}, a_{52}, a_{53}, a_{54}$ are four new positive reals. Denote the resulting $5 \times 5$-matrix by $B$. Then, this matrix $B$ is ...

Comment: ... the Laplacian matrix of a directed graph with $5$ vertices $1,2,3,4,5$ and arc weights $a_{ij}$ on the arcs from $i$ to $j$. The Matrix-Tree Theorem for directed graphs (see, e.g., Theorem 6 in [Lionel Levine's 18.312 class from 2011](http://math.mit.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-19.pdf), but replace multiple arcs by weighted arcs) shows that every principal $4 \times 4$-submatrix of $B$ has a positive determinant (and this determinant is a sum of the weights of all oriented spanning trees rooted at the one vertex which our submatrix avoids). Now, ...

Comment: ... we are not quite there yet, since $A'$ is not a principal submatrix of $B$, but rather the submatrix formed by removing the $5$-th row and the $4$-th column. However, I think we are close. The matrix $B$ (being a Laplacian matrix) is singular (i.e., has determinant $0$), and thus its adjugate $\operatorname{adj} B$ has rank $\leq 1$. In other words, all columns of $\operatorname{adj} B$ are proportional to each other. Moreover, all diagonal entries of $\operatorname{adj} B$ are determinants of principal $4\times 4$-submatrices of $B$, and thus are positive (as we have seen). ...

Comment: ... We want to prove that the $\left(4,5\right)$-th entry of $\operatorname{adj} B$ is positive (because that entry is $-\det\left(A'\right)$). Okay, this is not quite obvious yet. Instead, I need to invoke another fact closely related to the matrix-tree theorem: namely, the fact that the kernel of the Laplacian matrix $B$ is $1$-dimensional and is spanned by a vector with positive entries. (This follows, e.g., from Theorem 1 in [Siddhartha Sahi, *Harmonic vectors and matrix tree theorems*, arXiv:1309.4047v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4047v1), where elements of the ...

Comment: ... kernel of $B$ are called "harmonic vectors". But it is also fairly easy to see in other ways.) Let $v$ denote this vector with positive entries that spans $\operatorname{Ker} B$. But $\det B = 0$ entails that all columns of $\operatorname{adj} B$ belong to $\operatorname{Ker} B$, and thus are scalar multiples of $v$. Since the diagonal entries of $B$ are all positive, we furthermore know that the scalar factors are positive. Thus, all columns of $\operatorname{adj} B$ are positive scalar multiples of the positive vector $v$. Hence, all entries of $\operatorname{adj} B$ are positive. Done!

Answer (score 1):

In general, suppose $A$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix in the form of $\pmatrix{-M&b\\ c^T&a}$ where $a$ is a scalar, $b,c$ are positive vectors and $M$ is a strictly diagonally dominant matrix with a positive diagonal and non-positive off-diagonal entries.

By [Geršgorin disc theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), all eigenvalues of $M$ have positive real parts. Thus $\det(M)>0$ and $M$ is a [Z-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_(mathematics)) whose eigenvalues have positive real parts. It follows that $M$ is an [M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix) and $M^{-1}$ is entrywise positive. So, by using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we get
$$
\det(A)=\det(-M)(a+c^TM^{-1}b)=(-1)^{n-1}\det(M)(a+c^TM^{-1}b)
$$
and hence $\operatorname{sgn}(\det(A))=(-1)^{n-1}$. In your case, $n=4$ and hence $\det(A)<0$.